# Can't Import Files in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started using vscode and I am trying to import import forms and classes from other files in the same directory but it isn't working for some reason. It was working in pycharm so I copied all my code.

This is my main file to which I am importing:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from models import User, Post
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(),
                           Length(min = 2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(),
                            EqualTo('password')])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                      validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                     EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(),
                            EqualTo('password')])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from __main__ import db


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable= False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title }','{self.date_posted}')"
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: If all these files are under the same directory, perhaps try `from .forms import...`, notice the dot before `forms`

Comment: Can you describe your question with more information? What's the error and how does the error occur?

Comment: have you set a python interpreter path?

Comment: No how do I do that @Sevy ?

Comment: if you open some python file in vscode you can see "select interpreter path" at the bottom bar. if not it should select it automatically and the text says "python 3.x". if you want vscode to use your venv as an interpreter you have to click the button and select this manually.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder};"
  },
```

In the Pycharm it will be added default: `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH`. You can click `Edit Configurations` in the PyCharm to find it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me. I just jumped on vs code without really learning how to use it properly..

Comment: @icedcapp If it's helpful, could you accept and upvote it? thanks.

Comment: It worked but I tried the same code on another vscode window/folder by copy pasting. It works in one folder but doesn't on the other.. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @icedcapp Very sorry for being late. If you want to import the module or the python file, the parent folder path of the module or the python file needs to be added into the `PYTHONPATH` variable. As you have mentioned it works in the PyCharm while not working in the VSCode, the parent folder of your python file should be under your workspace folder. So you only need to add the `${workspaceFolder};`. But in fact, it is `${workspaceFolder}\xxx\parent folder your python file`.